# SELECT column mysql

Tags: php

I am in a little bit in doubt, if I am on the correct path here. I have a mysql database, where I have login details of users. I am making a profile page, where I would like the informations on a user is shown to the user. I am now trying to return the firstname there is a column in the database. Am I on the correct path with this code?

```
<td>
    Firstname
    <?php
      $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT firstname FROM login");

      $stmt->execute();

      $fname = null;

        $stmt->bind_result( $fname);

        while($stmt->fetch()) {
          $firstname = // Code here
          echo $firstname;
        }

      $stmt->close();
      $mysqli->close();
    ?>
  </td>
```

**Update:**

I tried to make the code a little bit smaller. This code actually retrives users, but it is all the users in the database, and not only the user I am logged into with. Should the SELECT query be asigned with the primarykey, if I only need the firstname on the current user I am logged in as?

```
<td>
    Firstname
    <?php
        $sql ="SELECT firstname FROM login;";
        $res = $mysqli->query($sql);
        //print($res);
        if($res){                                       
            while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
               echo $row['firstname'];

          }                               
        }
      ?>        
  </td>
```

Comment: What isn't working with your current code? Also, what code do you have in `// Code here`. That's a syntax error at present due to the missing semi-colon.

Comment: You already bound your `firstname` column to the `$fname` variable, so anytime you do `fetch()`, you're fetching the next name in the results into your `$fname` variable,s o your loop could just be `while($stmt->fetch()) { echo $fname; }`

Comment: I did not make the while loop yet, but it just seems as so much code to return a username?

Comment: Sure, if you have the "one" name in your db. You should use a `WHERE` clause for better precision.

Comment: I don't know you have considered it or not. But you need to put conditions in you SQL command. This query will return first_name for all users, but you need only username of current user. For example ```$mysqli->prepare("select firstname from login where id=$user_id");```. And then instead of **while** you can use an **if**, bucause you will have only one result (if id column is unique :) ).

Comment: Thank you a lot for all your answers. I just updated my question. I will just try to put a where clause

Comment: *"Should the SELECT query be asigned with the primary key"* - You can do that, sure; *why not?* - Plenty of ways to go about it really. But with one column selected, and if you have `lastname` in your db, you won't be able to do `echo $row['lastname'];` so you'd need to select it also.

Comment: btw, if this is a live site or intended to go live, I hope you're using or plan on using a safe hashing function to store passwords with.

Comment: Hello Fred. It is going live, but I am not so good yet, so I am doing everything I can, and then I have some friends who are really good at programming, and then we will go thorugh all my code, so I also learn something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're playing around with PHP and trying to learn how things work, you're on a great path. If you're planning on deploying this code to the internet, you have a few issues:

1. Your markup seems off. Why are you putting all of the first names in a single `<td>`?
2. You shouldn't have a SQL query happening inside of a markup. What if you want to show results from a cache or a text file some day? Ideally you wouldn't even mix PHP and HTML. Some folks use PHP's built-in templating abilities, but it's generally preferred to use a template language like jade or twig.
3. Your code alignment isn't consistent.

But if you're just seeing what PHP can do, good job. Keep trying stuff out. It's the best way to learn for most people. Others like reading a book, then trying stuff.

Comment: Hello Fuser. Thank you for your answer, and good points also. the `<td>` are inside a ´tbody´. This is just a testing site, so when my functions are working as they should, I will take them over to my real site, where I have divs, and seperate scripts folders, so the html and php not gonna be mixed. The consisdent is just because I test my functions, but it is maybe correct that I should be consistent on that one aswell

Answer (score 2):

You are on the correct path but you need to assign your array to a variable so you can print adding your column name in the scope and remove the bind of `$fname`

```
//$stmt->bind_result($fname);
while($column = $stmt->fetch()) {
     $firstname = $column['firstname'];
     echo $firstname;
}
```

Or you can just use the variable you bind before

```
$stmt->bind_result($fname);
while($stmt->fetch()) {
     echo $fname;
}
```

You could optimize your query and limit tresult to only one user by adding a `WHERE` condition to your query, you can use user ID for example

```
SELECT firstname FROM login WHERE userid = 1
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I will try it immedtly.

Comment: If I want to get the username, that I am logged into through my website, I have to use something like WHERE u_id=$user_id"); ?

Comment: Yeah, where do you have user id stored? Do you have a session or something?

Comment: Yes I have a session. The primarykey in the database is called u_id.

Comment: Is the userid stored in the session? If so you can use in your query `WHERE u_id = '$yoursessionuserid'`

Comment: hm my mistake, it is not saved anywhere within the session actually. Sorry

Comment: So you need to add in the sessuon and then use in your query

Comment: Hm I have to read about that then. I dont know how to do that :-( My code now echo all the firstnames from my database, because of a while loop. But I could also just make an if/else stamtement right? Then I would only get the firstname I want?

Comment: It would be better to know the userid using the page, how can you filter with an if clause if you don'r know actual user?

Comment: good point Fabio. So if I have stored the userid in session, I can also use that to identify other informations on the user, because the userid is unique, right?